# What are the different methods of factoring polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra

Methods of factoring . 
Method of common factors 
Factorization by regrouping terms 
Factorization using identities 
Factors of the form ( x + a) ( x + b) 
Factor by Splitting

Is this all the factoring methods out there ? Or are there more ? 
I am also looking for a book with lots of practice problems of factoring polynomials .

Please help

Answer (score 0):

On following site you can get to know about other techniques of factorization.
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/Factoring.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are considerably more advanced methods for factoring polynomials, such as that of [Berlekamp and Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm).

Comment: All those were never taught in my school or college , so i guess its OK to ignore it for my current level of studies . But thanks for that info :-)